# Pandas stack unstack pivot hierarchical index - reshape dataframe

Tags: stack, pandas, pivot, hierarchical

I have massaged a dataframe so it looks like this:

```
123
456
789
0AB
CDE
FGH
...
,,,
```

I would like to transform it, so it looks like this:

```
123789CDE...
4560ABFGH,,,
```

The pattern is this:

```
123 789 CDE ...
456 0AB FGH ,,,
```

That is, I take two rows and concatenate the next two rows, etc, so I get a wide dataframe.

But my real dataframe is not three columns, it is maybe 50 columns, and maybe 100,000 rows, so my dataframe is 100,000 x 50 big. I want to take 100 rows, and concatenate the next 100 rows, etc so I get a wide dataframe with dimension 100 x (50 * 100,000/100) = 100 x 50,000.

Can Pandas do this? My aim is to do some calculations on each of these 100 rows. Or is hierarchical indexing better?

Answer (score 1):

```
shell [33]>>> df
      [33]>>>
     0
0  123
1  456
2  789
3  0AB
4  CDE
5  FGH
6  ...
7  ,,,

shell [34]>>> pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(4, 2)).sum()
      [34]>>>
0    123789CDE...
1    4560ABFGH,,,
dtype: object
```

Another approach is using groupby.

```
shell [35]>>> df['group'] = 0

shell [36]>>> df[1::2]['group'] = 1

shell [37]>>> grouped = df.groupby('group')

shell [38]>>> grouped.sum()
      [38]>>>
                  0
group
0      123789CDE...
1      4560ABFGH,,,
```

Maybe worth studying not to create a new frame and instead work directly on the groups? Certainly for multiple columns and huge numnber of rows.

```
shell [39]>>> for key, group in grouped:
    print key
    print group
        ....:
0
     0  group
0  123      0
2  789      0
4  CDE      0
6  ...      0
1
     0  group
1  456      1
3  0AB      1
5  FGH      1
7  ,,,      1
```

Comment: Your approach with "reshape()" does not give the output
you gave. It gives:
>>...reshape(10,2)<newline>
123 456 789 0AB<newline>
CDE FGH ... ,,,<newline>
instead of:
123 789 CDE ...<newline>
456 0AB FGH ,,,<newline>

Thanks for teaching me about "groupby" which is better.
However, "grouped" is a DataFrameGroupBy object. I would like "grouped" to be an ordinary DataFrame object which I can work with. Now, the "grouped" object is a DataFrameGroupBy which I dont know how to work with. It does not have .ix(...) method, for instance. Can I transform "grouped" to a DataFrame?

Comment: PS. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate you pointed me in the right direction! :)

Comment: I have got groupby() solution to work, but I can not work with the individual groups. I need to look at all groups at the same time. Therefore I would like to have a very wide dataframe like this:
Group1 | Group2 | ... | Groupn (where each Group consists of 100 rows, concatenated by the next Group etc, so all Groups span the columns)
And now, I will look at the first row (which spans every group), and run some functions on each row. How should I do that?

Comment: Have a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html more specifically at the apply and transform sections

Comment: Thanks for your help everybody! I have solved the problem. First I add a new "group" column numbering each row. Then I use groupby to extract a sub dataframe consisting of each group. After that, I do pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) which concatenates the dataframes columnwise just as I wanted. Thanx! :)